# Newbie trying to figure out PHP

Tags: php

I am just trying to make a simple PHP program that allows me to generate my page quickly.

I am completely new at PHP.. And I have no clue what I am doing.

/index.php

```
<?php
  include "/base/startup.php";
  echo "Test";
  startPage("Home");
 ?>
```

I'm getting a 500 server error with this.. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

/base/startup.php

```
$HOME = "/";
$SCRIPT = <<<EOD

EOD;

$IMPORTS = array(
  "/scripts/script.js"
);

$STYLES = array(
  "/styles/style.css"
);

function prnt($string) {
  echo $string;
}

function map($func, $arr) {
  foreach($arr as $i) {
    call_user_func($func, $i);
  }
}

function linkScript($script) {
  prnt("<script src='$script'></script>");
}

function linkStyle($style)  {
  prnt("<link rel='stylesheet' href='$style'/>");
}

function startPage($title, $script="", $imports=array(), $styles=array()) {
  $pre_tags = array(
    "<html>",
    "<head>"
  );
  $post_tags = array(
    "</head>",
    "<body>"
  );
  map(prnt, $pre_tags);
  prnt("<title>$title</title>");
  map(linkScript, $IMPORTS);
  map(linkScript, $imports);
  map(linkStyle, $STYLES);
  map(linkStyle, $styles);
  map(prnt, $post_tags);
}

function genNav() {
  $nav_links = array(
    "Home"=>$HOME,
    "Walkthroughs"=>$HOME . "/walkthroughs/",
    "Dex"=>$HOME . "dex.php"
  );
  prnt("<div class='nav'>");
  foreach ($nav_links as $key => $value) {
    prnt("<a class='link' href='" . $value . "'/>" . $key . "</a>");
  }
}

function endPage() {
  $endTags = array(
    "</body>",
    "</html>"
  );
}

 ?>
```

This is the error:

```
Warning: include(/base/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/base/startup.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
Test
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function startPage() in /var/www/html/index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
```

Comment: Have you enabled `display_errors` in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am on linux

Comment: I don't find any syntax errors with your code. So it should be some runtime error. Please enable `display_errors` by adding `ini_set("display_errors", 1)` on top of your code.

Comment: Also see this answer for understanding how to enable errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings And please tell us what's the error you are getting.

Comment: Try removing the `/` in the `include`. Change it to: `include "base/startup.php";`

Comment: @script8man try `/etc/php.ini` or `/etc/php/php.ini`. If you still can't find it: Create an otherwise empty php file (for example named `info.php`) and just write `<?php phpinfo();` in it.

Comment: @ccKep I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: It's probably what @PraveenKumar said. You're trying to include the wrong file (there is probably no `/base` on your system?).

Comment: @script8man Did it work?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Nope..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are on a Linux machine, it looks like the issue is caused because of the `/` here. The `/` is considered the root directory of linux machine. So removing the `/` must most probably work:

```
<?php
  include "base/startup.php";  // Try removing the slash.
  echo "Test";
  startPage("Home");
?>
```

Since you haven't enabled the display of errors, the issue would be, there's no `/base` in your system and it would have thrown an error, like **Fatal: Include file not found.**, which is not displayed because of your configuration, instead it would have shown **Error 500** silently.

---

**Update**

Along with the above error, after seeing your code, the next one is you need to quote the function names. So replace the stuff with:

```
map("prnt", $pre_tags);
prnt("<title>$title</title>");
map("linkScript", $IMPORTS);
map("linkScript", $imports);
map("linkStyle", $STYLES);
map("linkStyle", $styles);
map("prnt", $post_tags);
```

---

The next error is, you haven't included the global variables correctly inside the function. You need to use:

```
global $IMPORTS, $STYLES;
```

Now your code works as expected.

---

And finally finishing the `endPage()` function:

```
function endPage() {
  $endTags = array(
    "</body>",
    "</html>"
  );
  foreach($endTags as $tag)
    echo $tag;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to enable errors..

Comment: @script8man Did you try the solution first? I gave you a link on understanding how to enable errors. Did you even see that?

Comment: @script8man FYI: Also see this answer for understanding how to enable errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/ And please tell us what's the error you are getting.

Comment: I managed to turn on errors. I'll link them in an edit.

Comment: @script8man Perfect. Waiting for it.

Comment: It's here.. Hopefully this helps

Comment: @script8man As I said you, you haven't removed the `/` in front right. Can you try removing the `/` and see what's happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113780/discussion-between-script8man-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: Including with relative paths is bad. The way to go is explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory